# generate random tree using python

Tags: python, html, xml, tree

How can I generate a random tree in python. I have an array from which I want to generate a random tree. I have the following code with me:

```
class Testcase(object):        
    def generateRandomTree(depth, p):
        '''
        depth = max length of path
        p = probability for another child on one level
        '''
        raise NotImplementedError()

def main():
    t = Testcase();
    t.generateRandomTree(3, 0.4)

main()
```

Can anyone tell me how can I generate random tree?

Comment: Have you tried implementing it yourself? We're not going to write the code for you, but we can help you if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

1. figure out how to represent a tree data structure
2. figure out how to generate a non-random (full) tree of given depth
3. add a random number test to the code from step 2, just before adding each child

NB. You don't say if it's meant to be a *binary* tree, or have an arbitrary number of children, or whether you *must* reach the stated depth or only not exceed it.